# Can Java objects be accessed from Javascript in GWT?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, rpc

My goal is to initiate RPC calls directly from javascript.  I have come up with ways to fake callbacks (because of the asynchronous nature of RPC) but I can't figure out how to get custom objects into javascript.

So, I've created a class named Interop and I statically create the service I'm interested in (had to use static as it was all I could get working, I don't think it's relevant right now):

```
public class Interop {
    private static final GreetingServiceAsync service = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);
    ...
}
```

I then create a function that will do the async calls and handle the responses:

```
public static void greetServer(final String success, final String failure) {
    service.greetServer(
        "Homer", 
        new AsyncCallback<String>() {
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                callback(failure, caught.toString());

            }
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                callback(success, result);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Then I create a JSNI function to export this function to javascript which I call from the onModuleLoad():

```
public static native void export() /*-{
    $wnd.greetServer = $entry(@package.Interop::greetServer(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;));
}-*/;
```

And also create another JSNI function to deal with the callbacks:

```
public static native void callback(String func, String response) /*-{
    $wnd[func](response);
}-*/;
```

So that the function names I pass into greetServer() initially for success and failure are called by the JSNI as callbacks.  And this all works great when dealing with Strings or (I assume) a primitive type.  But when I try to do this with custom types (note the altered Custom type parameter):

```
public static native void callback(String func, Custom response) /*-{
    $wnd[func](response);
}-*/;
```

Then what ends up in javascript doesn't work.  It seems to be a javascript object with cascading arrays and none of the methods are available.

So, the question is, how can Java-originated objects that aren't basic or primitives be accessed from within javascript (not JSNI)?  From what I can tell JavaScriptObject needs to originate in javascript, but in my case, my objects are originating in Java.  What can I do?

I've also looked into gwt-exporter and that shows how to instantiate java stuff from javascript, but not how to access java-originated stuff in javascript.

I know this is a bit confusing so please let me know if you have any questions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With gwt-exporter this could be your code:

```
// Create and export a closure used to wrap javascript callbacks
@ExportClosure
public static interface InteropCallback extends Exportable {
  void exec(String message);
}

// Make your Interop class exportable and export methods in it
@ExportPackage("foo")
@Export
public static class Interop implements Exportable {
  final static GreetingServiceAsync service = GWT.create(GreetingService.class);

  public static void greeting(String message, 
                              final InteropCallback success,
                              final InteropCallback error) {
    service.greetServer(message, new AsyncCallback<String>() {
      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
        error.exec(caught.getMessage());
      }
      public void onSuccess(String result) {
        success.exec(result);
      }
    });
  }
}

// In your onModuleLoad you have to make gwt-exporter export your stuff
@Override public void onModuleLoad() {
  ExporterUtil.exportAll();
  ...
}
```

Finally call your java methods from handwritten javascript

```
window.foo.Interop.greeting("Hello", 
                            function(s){console.log(s)},
                            function(s){console.log(s)}
                            );
```

Comment: Sorry it has taken a while to respond but thanks for the input! Your examples certainly seem to be working for me and will be a great starting point.  I think I misinterpreted something and may not even need to use gwt-exporter, but it's nice to know it is there if I need it.  Thanks!